# Why is Mysql2 queuing statements until the loop is finished?

Tags: javascript, mysql, mysql2

When executing the following code mysql doesn't start doing anything until the loop is done executing. If i await pool.execute it starts right away and inserts them one at a time, which is expected. But if unawaited I'd expect mysql2 to start executing as many statements as I have connections available in the pool and queue the rest. What's going on?

```
import mysql from 'mysql2'
const pool = mysql.createPool(MYSQL_CONFIG)
const pool = pool.promise()

for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {     
    pool.execute(`
        INSERT INTO table (id) values(?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id
    `, [id])
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. Unless the pool is implemented as a worker thread, it doesn't do anything until the main code returns to the event loop.